# Javascript-combine multiple condition to 1

Tags: javascript

Is there a better way in Javascript to check for multiple elements for their length. I want to check length of following arrays if they are greater than 0, I do:

```
a=[]; b=[1,2,3]; c=[db, gf, gf]; d=[]; e=[1,2,3]; f=[db, gf, gf]; g=[44,56,77]; 
h=[1,2,3]; i=[db, gf, gf];j=[]; e=[1,2,3]; k=[db, gf, gf]; l=[44,56,77]; 
m=[1,2,3]; n=[db, gf, gf]
```

So in total I have 14 arrays of diff values for diff condition and I want to apply just one solution to all of them if length ===0.

```
if (a.length === 0 || b.length === 0|| c.length === 0|| d.length < 0|| e.length === 0|| f.length === 0|| g.length === 0|| h.length === 0|| i.length === 0|| j.length === 0|| k.length === 0|| l.length === 0|| m.length === 0|| n.length === 0){
// set some field to false
}
```

is there a better way to check length, as this may get cumbersome if we have more arrays added
Thanks!

Comment: why not use an array for the arrays?

Comment: an array length should never be less than 0...

Comment: sorry I meant ```===```, updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all the arrays in another array, then use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
if ([a, b, c, d, e, f, g, j, i, j, k, l, m, n].some(x => x.length > 0)) {
    // do something
}
```

If you want to test if something is true for *all* the arrays, not just any of them, use `every` instead of `some`.

Answer (score 1):

If you put all your arrays in another array you can use `array.every()`:

```js
a=[]; b=[1,2,3]; c=['db', 'gf', 'gf']; d=[]; e=[1,2,3]; f=['db', 'gf', 'gf']; g=[44,56,77]; 
h=[1,2,3]; i=['db', 'gf', 'gf'];j=[]; e=[1,2,3]; k=['db', 'gf', 'gf']; l=[44,56,77]; 
m=[1,2,3]; n=['db', 'gf', 'gf']

let valid = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n].every(arr => arr.length > 0)
// nope some emtpies
console.log(valid)

// add something to the empty arrays
j.push(1)
d.push(2)
a.push("df")

valid = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n].every(arr => arr.length > 0)
// now valid
console.log(valid)
```

You might consider putting all this data in an array or object to start with; it will make things like this easier and will help organize your data.

Answer (score 1):

[`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) are your friends here.  Just put your values into an array of their own and check in this case with `some`:

```js
let a = [], b = [1,2,3], c = ['db', 'gf', 'gf'], d = [], e = [1,2,3], f = ['db', 'gf', 'gf'],
    g = [44,56,77], h = [1,2,3], i = ['db', 'gf', 'gf'], j = [], k = ['db', 'gf', 'gf'], 
    l = [44,56,77], m = [1,2,3], n = ['db', 'gf', 'gf'];
    
if ([a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n].some(arr => arr.length === 0)) {
  console.log('found empties');
} else {
  console.log('no empties');
}

if ([a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n].some(arr => arr.length > 5)) {
  console.log('found large');
} else {
  console.log('no large');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code

```
for (var i = 65; i <= 78; i++) {
    if(window[String.fromCharCode(i)] < 0){
        // write code here
        // break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work only when variable are global variable not in functions

Comment: Furthermore, it only works it only work if the variables are named after the alphabet.

Comment: This approach looks very fragile.  I would assume that in the actual problem, the values are not `[1, 2, 3]`, etc.  And quite possibly the names are not `a`, `b`, `c`, etc.

Comment: Yes It will work if variable name are alphabet, You can create array of simple variable like varaiableArray = ["var1", "var2"].. and then use this array instead of the string.fromcharecode